# Pattern for Using an Access Code with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently using Firebase for my app, and I'd like to make parts of my application to not only require user authorization but to also be private and require a user to input an access code to gain entry.

I've already got the authorization piece working with a few different providers and anonymous authentication. My question is, is there a proper pattern already existing for above functionality? Or do I need to write a separate web service to handle this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add security to your database you better check this out the Firebase documentation about [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/)

In the `database console` under the `Rules` you will find the section to add security to your database. Basically it's a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

In the example above I just declare that for the complete database to read and write there should be a logged in user.

In the same way I recommend you to read the auth section of the documentation and how to implement it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes).

**EDITED**

Because the example above wasn't clear enough I made another one in my Firebase database. In this example I have a path `https://*****.firebaseio.com/users`. In the example below you can see that I assigned `true` to the `.read` property and `auth != null` to the `.write` property, it means that everyone can read this path but only authenticated users can write in this path.

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users":{
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
  }
}
```

Using the Firebase simulator you can see that read is enable when you are not authenticated.
[image]

But if I want to write without authenticate myself I got an error.
[image]

Now if I use authentication in the simulator I can perform a write operation.
[image]

**EDITED VERSION 2 "ACCESS TOKEN"**

Ok I see what you mean. I assume you are going to store this "access code" somewhere in your Firebase database. If you want to validate data within the database to allow read or write you can do it as the documentat says [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#root).

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "root.child('access_token').child(auth.uid).exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above I have a path in the database called `access_token`, in this path I stored a key pair user_uid-accessToken and then using the `root` property make a query to validate if you have a value for the authenticated user in this path. I'm using the `exists()` but there are many others methods you can use to make this validation. For example if the access code is hardcoded then you can use the `val()` method to compare for an exact value.

Comment: My firebase database is secured using my custom security rules. This question is specifically for a pattern for creating an area of the database that is inaccessible until an authenticated user has entered the access code.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly, by adding the code above only authenticated users can read or write in the database regardless your custom security rules. `"auth != null"` means that only authenticated users (using Firebase authentication) can read or write. Is not that what you want?

Comment: I'm realizing now I need to edit my question. This would be for a user who is already authenticated, but I need to lock down a piece of the structure until a user inputs a proper access code. So the rules would be 1. user is authenticated (the easy part) and 2. user enters the correct access code (the hardish part)

Comment: I edited the post to show you how you can accomplish the access code validation.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was very helpful. I'm going to mark it as answer, however I've decided to go a bit of a different path. You started me in the correct direction though, and I'm sure others will be grateful for this answer.